# io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aventstack/extentreports/reporter/ReporterConfigurable

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured, extentreports

I'm trying to implement **Extent Reports** in my API automation project, for that I have added the dependencies for your reference.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

       <!-- Extent Report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

       <!-- Cucumber ExtentReport Adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber5-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and added the plugin part in the Cucumber Runner class.

```
plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}
```

When I run the script, getting the below error.

**io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aventstack/extentreports/reporter/ReporterConfigurable**

Can you please help me to resolve this issue ?

**Note:** Its working with info.cukes cucumber and vimalselvam extent report.

Thanks, 
Karunagara Pandi G

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for the above issue. I have added the adapter dependency (which matches with io.cucumber 5.7.0 version) in my pom.xml and removed aventstack dependency as its not required.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
 <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber5-adapter</artifactId>
 <version>2.15.0</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```